# Perl's grep gives different results when used with or without qr

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I'm trying to use grep with a variable regex. I assumed that the following program would print nothing, since the regex `/food/` doesn't match any of the items in my array.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my @arry = qw/foo bar baz/;
my $regex = "food";

say join ",", grep { qr/$regex/ } @arry;
```

But the output says otherwise:

```
foo,bar,baz
```

When I take out the `qr`, I get the results I expected (i.e. nothing matches). What is `qr` doing to cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`qr//` is a value, and doesn't match against `$_`. A regex object is always true in boolean context.

You want to apply the regex, e.g like

```
grep $_ =~ qr/$regex/, @array;
```

but that is silly. Use the normal `m//` match operator or variations of it:

```
grep /$regex/, @array;
```

This should then produce empty output.

---

The `qr//` quote operator makes composing regexes easier, as it has the same parsing rules as ordinary regexes in `m//` or `s///`. The value of `qr//` literals is a regexp object, which can be assigned to a variable, and can then be interpolated. This allows code like

```
my $foobarbaz = qr/\s*(?:foo|bar|baz)\s*/; # not regexp parsing rules at work for \s
local $_ = "bar  foo baz";
say m/${foobarbaz}{2,}/ ? 1 : 0; # use this to compose a regex
```

Comment: I would phrase it "`qr//` *creates* a regex object; it doesn't do any matching until that object is used via `=~`.  Since a regex object is true in boolean context, the grep passes through everything."

Answer (score 5):

As [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17711327/15168), the `qr//` construct creates a regex object which is never false, so the use of `grep { qr/anything/ } @arry` selects everything in the array.

This is how you might use a `qr` regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my @arry = qw/foo bar baz dog food/;
my $regex = "food";
my $qr = qr/$regex/;

say "[", join ",", grep({ qr/$regex/ } @arry), "]"; # Original
say "[", join ",", grep({ $_ =~ $qr  } @arry), "]"; # Modified
say $qr;                                            # Stringized
```

The output is as you'd expect:

```
[foo,bar,baz,dog,food,]
[food,]
(?^:food)
```

The parentheses are necessary to limit the scope of the `grep` (otherwise, the `"]"` is passed as an extra argument to `grep`, not `say`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `qr//` in the `grep` block, use it in the definition of your `$regex` variable. Since `qr//` is a value (in particular, a compiled regex), it doesn't actually attempt to match anything. Since you've put the `qr//` in a boolean context, it will always be `true`.

It might be easier to just use the normal `m//` operator like this: `grep /$regex/, @arry;`

If for some reason you really want to have a precompiled regex before using `grep` against the array, try this instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my @arry = qw/foo bar baz/;
my $regex = qr/food/;

say join ",", grep { /$regex/ } @arry;
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for some examples on how the `qr//` operator works.

Comment: This is exactly the same thing that amon said, except I said it much less elegantly. Apologies for the redundancy.